# Как вывести текст в любую часть экрана?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Необходимо вывести текст в координаты *x, y* на дисплей,. Не в само окошко программы, а на *desktop*, любое другое окно других программ по заданным координатам *x, y*. Использую *Qt*, пробовал так, но ничего не вышло:

```
QPainter painter();
painter.setFont(QFont("Times", 25, QFont::Normal));
painter.drawText(0,0, "Draw text ");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы вывел с помощью `QLabel` с прозрачным фоном, навскидку:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setWindowFlag(Qt::SplashScreen); //убираем рамки
label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); 
//setStyleSheet c помощью него задаем размеры, цвет текста
label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : blue; font-size:36px}");
QString text = "I am textaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
label->setText(text);
//А тут мой минихак с заданием width и height под размер текста 
label->adjustSize();
int w = label->width();
int h =  label->height();
//0, 0 - координаты куда будем текст помещать
label->setGeometry(0, 0, w, h);   
label->adjustSize();
label->show();
```

Положение задаем с помощью `setGeometry`, размеры я задал от фонаря, а потом с помощью `adjustSize` подогнал их под контент

Comment: Спс все работает. Я немного дописал ответ, послав на правку добавив задание стиля текста и подгонку под размер.

Comment: @MadokaMagica: не обязательно размер выставлять, если вы его не используете (можно `move(x,y)` использовать, вместо `setGeometry()`). Можно FramelessWindowHint вместо SplashScreen. [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/62227e5e360fd2a5316c74af9497f42b)