# Как вывести текст в любую часть экрана поверх всех окон?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5

Я знаю уже задавал похожий вопрос и на него ответили ([тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707471/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)) но это не дубликат

Проблема в том что текст перекрывается любым окном, а мне надо чтобы он не перекрывался, и был поверх всех окон, можно ли такое сделать? Также очень хорошо но это уже не обязательно, чтобы координаты текста были иногда привязаны к самому окну.

Comment: Надо добавить флаг Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint чтобы тот лейбл был расположен поверх всех окон

Comment: Спс большое. Работает. Я кидал другие флаги, но этот не догадался. Напишите если хотите в ответы я его прийму.